# How to update/insert the status (one column) in the GridView by selecting a value from DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two tables in my database as following:

Suggestions Table: ID, Title, Description, StatusID... etc

SuggestionsStatus Table: ID, Status

I am using GridView to show the Suggestions and in the last column I put a DropDownList that for selecting the status for each Suggestion. Now, when I tried to update the Status of one of the submitted suggestions by selecting the status from the DropDownList, the value has been selected but it wasn't inserted to the Database (which means still I have NULL value in the StatusID column in the Suggestions Table) and I don't know why.

My ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
                        width="950px" CssClass="mGrid"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
                        RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold = "true" ForeColor="Black" Height="20px"/> 
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                    SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
                    SortExpression="Username" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionShortcut" HeaderText="Division" 
                    SortExpression="DivisionShortcut" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
                                          Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#006666" AppendDataBoundItems="false" 
                                          DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                          OnDataBound="DropDownList_DataBound">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT     dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.ID, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Title, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Description, dbo.employee.Name, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username, 
                      dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut
FROM         dbo.employee INNER JOIN
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Divisions ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode"
                      FilterExpression="[DivisionShortcut] like '{0}%'">

                      <FilterParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision" Name="DivisionShortcut" 
                                                 PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                    </FilterParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <%--For the DropDownList--%>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SafetySuggestionsStatus]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My code-behind:

```
protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    int suggestionStatus = int.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue);
    //For inserting the status in the database
    string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
    string updateCommand = "UPDATE SafetySuggestionsLog  SET [StatusID] = @StatusID";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusID", suggestionStatus);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

it works but it will update the status for all submitted suggestions.

**So how I can fix this problem to be able to update the status of one of the submitted Suggestions in the (GridView) in the database?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the update statement to include the id for the record something like:

```
UPDATE SafetySuggestionsLog  SET [StatusID] = @StatusID WHERE SafetySuggestionId = @SafetySuggestionId
```

To get the id for the update you will need to do something like in this post to get the row index and then use that to find the id: [get selected row index of dynamic dropdown list selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928131/get-selected-row-index-of-dynamic-dropdown-list-selection)

Regards
Andy

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that post is difficult to understand, so could you please provide me with the code snippet?

Comment: The idea is that you take the drop dropdown list which is the sender and get the parent. You then keep getting the parents parent until you reach the element you need which would be a DataRow in your case I think. Once you have the data row you can then get to the DataCell that contains the ID you need for the update. I am sure you will get it working soon, good luck